# Make [office365-restapi] a synonym for [office365api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Microsoft Office 365 exposes [a series of REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog) to access their data.

These APIs are currently being discussed in two tags: [office365api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office365api) and [office365-restapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office365-restapi).

My request is to make [office365api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office365api) a master tag, and have [office365-restapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office365-restapi) be a synonym of that master tag.

Comment: Maybe find a user e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3307985/jason-johnston?tab=tags  "with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms" and send them a message to get them to propose it via http://stackoverflow.com/tags/office365-restapi/synonyms

Comment: There is no way to send messages within stackoverflow right? You are suggesting I message him outside of this site?

Comment: There is, comment on one of the answers he has posted or use @username in a comment thread that he has posted in.   Maybe with a link to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I've synonymized both the posts in the following direction

[office365api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office365api) ← [office365-restapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office365-restapi)

At the time of the synonymization, the tags had 670 and 261 posts respectively.